# Would there be any security downside to text-message "verification codes" saying what they're for?

Tags: authentication, social-engineering

When I log into some web services, I need to send back a verification code contained in a text message that starts out with something to the effect of "You or someone claiming to be you is trying to do X on service Y.  If you are trying to do X on service Y, the verification code is Z.  If you realize you may have fraudulently given this code to any person or web site, visit security.Y.com immediately."

With a different popular on-line service (which I'll call "Acme"), however, the text message is simply "Your Acme verification code is A-123456", but some phones will augment that with a phone-generated message saying "This is an authentic Acme security alert".

Is there any security downside to using text messages that are more like the former than the latter?  The latter approach is rife for a variety of social engineering attacks where someone dealing with a scammer or phony web site is told to expect a security code from them, but the scammer is actually seeking to gain access to the person's Acme account.  If there would be no security downside to the former approach, why would any large companies not use it?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen big corporations with professional security departments who have security policies that state the purpose of the verification code should included in the text message. Like you suggest to do. So there is precedence for your idea.

I would recommend to keep the message short. People will be less likely to read the entire message if it is long.

Additionally be careful not to provide too much details in case the message ends up in the wrong place.
Better "Verification code for log in to account myc***il@mail.com, code AB-5546", than "Verification code for log in to account mycoolmail@mail.com, code AB-5546". The second one potentially leaks the email address, whereas the first one doesn't but will still be recognizable.

As a side note. Text based One Time Passwords (OTP) are susceptible to attacks, such as SIM swapping, where the attacker takes control of the victims phone number and will receive the OTPs instead. Time based OTPs, don't have this problem. Source: https://www.cnet.com/tech/services-and-software/do-you-use-sms-for-two-factor-authentication-heres-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: Keeping the message short means that many devices will display it when it is received, even if they are locked.  That may be convenient, but would make it allow someone who steals a person's phone to use it to gain access to the person's accounts even if the phone is locked.

Comment: Good point. If you want to protect against that you could make the message long enough to make sure that the code itself won't be visible on the lock screen of most devices in use by your target audience. Though this attack's physical requirements mean that the pool of attackers is a lot smaller those doing remote attacks. If your specific use case is at high risk of this attack vector you might want to protect against it.

Comment: I think that much of the use case of keeping phones locked is preventing their use to leverage other accounts.  IMHO, there should be an agreed-upon convention between phone vendors and web services using SMS authentication to indicate what parts of a message should be hidden when phones are locked, but even without that putting a number near the end of a 140-character message would likely have such an effect if anything would.